# Inicio de sesión con Facebook API url bloqueada

Tags: php, api, facebook, oauth

Buenas noches
Estoy intentando de iniciar sesión utilizando la API de Facebook pero me aparece el siguiente error.
[image: Error]

Así es como tengo configurada la aplicación:
[image: app conf]

Éste es el código de "pruebaFacebook.php":

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/src/Facebook/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'mi_app_id',
  'app_secret' => 'mi_app_secret',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email', 'user_likes'];
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://powergraph.000webhostapp.com/prueba.php', $permissions);

echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
?>
```

Gracias de antemano y un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya está solucionado, el fallo estaba en que había introducido la URI de redirección de OAuth válido con "https" en vez de "http" ya que la url correcta no era segura.

Answer (score -1):

Prueba de esta manera para resolver tu error:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/src/Facebook/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'mi_app_id',
  'app_secret' => 'mi_app_secret',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email', 'user_likes'];
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://powergraph.000webhostapp.com/prueba.php', $permissions);

echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
?>
```